# Calling a Function From a String With the Function’s Name in Clojure

Tags: clojure

How could I call a function with a string? e.g. something like this:

```
(call "zero?" 1) ;=> false
```

Comment: It doesn't work in clojurescript.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A simple answer:

```
(defn call [this & that]
  (apply (resolve (symbol this)) that))

(call "zero?" 1) 
;=> false
```

Just for fun:

```
(defn call [this & that]
  (cond 
   (string? this) (apply (resolve (symbol this)) that)
   (fn? this)     (apply this that)
   :else          (conj that this)))

(call "+" 1 2 3) ;=> 6
(call + 1 2 3)   ;=> 6
(call 1 2 3)     ;=> (1 2 3)
```

Answer (score 29):

Something like:

```
(defn call [^String nm & args]
    (when-let [fun (ns-resolve *ns* (symbol nm))]
        (apply fun args)))
```

Comment: Thanks, `ns-resolve` in particular was what I was looking for.

Comment: it's better also to combine ns-resolve together with fn? to check, that symbol is function